# JPanel is messed up after adding another JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Hi I'm making my ui with `JFrame` and this is my code

```
private static void prepareUI(JPanel jPanel) {
    jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter Full Text Below"));

    {
        textInput = new JTextArea(5, 1);
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textInput);
        jPanel.add(jScrollPane);
    }

    {
        JSeparator jSeparator = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        jSeparator.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
        jPanel.add(jSeparator);
    }

    jPanel.add(new JLabel("Or Enter URL And Press Enter"));

    //url
    {
        urlInput = new JTextField(1);
        jPanel.add(urlInput);
    }

    {
        JSeparator jSeparator = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        jSeparator.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
        jPanel.add(jSeparator);
    }

    jPanel.add(new JLabel("Or"));

    {
        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel1,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JButton jButton = new JButton("Browse");
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(1);
        jPanel1.add(jTextField);
        jPanel1.add(jButton);
        jPanel.add(jPanel1);
    }

    {
        JButton jButton = new JButton("Find Matches");
        jPanel.add(jButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    {
        JButton jButton = new JButton("Matches");
        jPanel.add(jButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

but the output is not what i expected

[image]

you can see the second `JTextField` new Browse `JButton` is so small and not taking the whole parent and also `JLabel`s are not in the left side. How can i fix it?

**Edit: I removed `setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1))` and added column size 1 to all `JTextField`s but it's not fixed yet. `JTextField` is more than 1 line height and `JLabel` is not in left side.**

Answer (score 1):

```
jTextField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
```

Don't try to manually set a size restriction. I would guess a components can't display with a height of 1.

To suggest a size for a JTextField you would use:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

Then the text field will be sized to hold 10 "W" characters.

Edit:

Also, when you create a JTextArea you use:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

to suggest the number of row/columns you need. The component will then calculate its size.

Comment: I'm doing that because without it `JTextField` takes whole height of `JPanel` and `JTextArea` gets very small

Comment: You add you text field to a JPanel using a FlowLayout. The FlowLayout respects the size of the component, so there is no way the text field added to the panel with the button will grow in height. So you above comment makes no sense. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Also, see edit.

Comment: 1) that is not an [mcve]. How does that code compile? If you want help then take the time to include a proper `MCVE`. 2) I have no idea what you changed or why you changed it.

Comment: 1) Apparently you don't want help. Where is your [mcve]??? 2) I already told you a FlowLayout repects a components size. 3) Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use different Layout for JPanel. For your design, you can use `GridBagLayout`. It is responsive and makes management of your widgets easier.